# Cordova vs Ionic-Capacitor for WebGL (three.js) - Android App

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, webgl, capacitor

I'm porting a web desktop-application I made some years ago, to Android.
The application lets you configure the structure of a cemetery and everything related to it, it uses WebGL (three.js) and CSS ( CSS3DRenderer ) to render the grapichs.

I first tried a build using Cordova and I have very low performance on a low-end Android11 Tablet, especially on CSS animations.
I then tried building it on Ionic-Capacitor (compiled on Android Studio, everything updated) but it doesn't seem to have made any difference, still the same low performance (about 6 FPS on filled areas of the screen).

Now I know Capacitor is based on Cordova, but I read Cordova is still using the old deprecated webview and I tought this could had been one of the causes for the low performance. But I don't notice any difference performance wise.

Did anyone did some tests about the performance of both?
Do you have any recommendation about what's the best for WebGL based webapps on Android?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't notice any difference in performance in rendering WebGL and CSS, it seems it doesn't make any difference in my specific case, performance wise.
So I went for Cordova because I already used it in the past.